# How to deal with several markers in the same location on a map, e.g. to let viewers know they're there, and regarding tooltips with different info

Tags: web-mapping, markers, jupyter-notebook

I've created a web map. There are **several markers** on it, each representing something, and a tooltip shows related info.

Several markers are **in the very same location** (lat, lon).
So there are two problems:

1. you **can't say how many** markers are there actually, where you see a marker, one? Or 4, or... 1000?
2. you **can't access the info** for each marker, using the **tooltip**, because you can trigger only the top marker's tooltip.

How do you deal with this kind of situation?

I'm using [Kepler.gl](https://kepler.gl/) for Jupyter, so it would be nice to find a specific solution for it, but not necessary: I'm interested in understanding if there are some (technical and/or practical) solutions for this kind of cases, for web maps.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't your exact technology, but you might want to look through the code for some of [Leaflet's Clustering/Decluttering plugins](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#clusteringdecluttering).

If I recall, we use the [Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) plugin in our stuff. It looks kinda like this..

[image]

Then, if you click on one of the clustering icons (I chose a VERY busy one for example), notice how it offsets the individual icons that would otherwise be overlapping using a spiral sequence? I'm pretty sure they just take the icon's original coordinates (that is, screen or div coordinates) then adjust them against a Fibonacci sequence..

[image]

Unfortunately it looks like the screenshotting process removed our icon popups from these examples for some reason, but hopefully this is enough to give you some ideas.

I'm not familiar with `Kepler.gl` and honestly have never heard of it, which makes me think finding something ready-to-go will be difficult. However if you're knee-deep into some application development around it, I suspect it wouldn't be too difficult to adapt a mechanism for icon offsetting, and IMO the plugin I demonstrated made a wise choice to use a Fibonacci displacement, because it will scale very well depending on whether you have 4 or 400 features all clustered together. I hope this helps.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of technical and/or practical solution that I was searching for.
Yes, that Fibonacci displacement is a smart move.